# Avoiding having multiple containers in Docker

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker and often have to build containers multiple time.

I'm using the following command: `docker build -t sometag:someversion .` which each time creates a new container (as I've later figured it out).

Is there a way to have just one container after each build happens?

Or I just need to remove container after it exits with a command like this: `docker run --rm my-image` and not using `docker build`?

Comment: Docker build will create an image not container, images become containers at runtime. My guess is that you have a lot of `<none>` images after you have built a certain image several times. To remove all dangling images (stoped containers as well!) at one you could run `docker system prune` command.

Comment: If you are iterating on a Dockerfile, then yes, you will wind up with lots of stale images and will wind up starting test containers a lot.  This is pretty normal.

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing up images (which basically are "blueprints", and the result of *"docker build"*) and containers : those are the instances that will run from this image.

When you perform a ***docker build***, even with no tag specification, it will still replace previous **image**, but not destroying it. Instead, it will untag it (you'll see a  tag instead).

When you perform a ***docker run***, you will create a **container** from this image. When you stop it, it will not remove the container : you can see all stopped containers with the *"docker ps -a"*  command. If you want to remove it, you have to *"docker rm "* it.

Ok, but sometimes, you want to do some more efficient (and general) **cleaning**... eg when you have unremoved containers or old dangling images.
In this case, docker provide the "**prune**" action, that can be performed on any kind of docker object : image, volume, container, network, config and secret (I may have forgotten some but that's the basic idea).
To do such, type

```
'docker <one among above object> prune'
```

(that's pretty magic)....

Note that if some of these objects are still linked to other non-removed objects, they need to be "pruned", first : eg, if you have a stopped (but not removed) container still using an untagged image, you have to remove the container first!

Also note that you may have to download back some images after "*image prune*" if they were not used anymore (which is a problem if they are not available anymore!)

Eventually, you can clean the whole of them using the system prune :

```
"docker system prune"*
```

which is convenient... but not really subtle!